# Why do i get an empty payload from Auth0 when using auth0-react package?

Tags: reactjs, passport.js, apollo, auth0

I'm working on switching authentication in my node/react/apollo app from passport-jwt to Auth0.

Auth0 is returning an empty payload in the JWT access token, so I don't get any user information.

There are a few posts in Auth0's forums that suggest the issue is that the `audience` isn't being passed to Auth0's auth endpoint. However, I'm not calling Auth0's auth endpoint directly--`@auth0/auth0-react` seems to be doing that for me. Looking at the network tab on developer tools, I can see that an audience parameter is being passed in the get request to /authorize.

Here is the request with values removed:
`https://<domain>.us.auth0.com/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3001&audience=<client_id>&scope=openid profile email&response_type=code&response_mode=query&state=<string>==&nonce=<string>==&code_challenge=<string>&code_challenge_method=S256&auth0Client=<string>=

I've followed the set up described by an Auth0 and an Apollo developer advocate in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqHkwTWbaUk&themeRefresh=1).

I have a button that triggers the `loginWithRedirect` from the auth0-react library:

```
          <button
            onClick={() =>
              loginWithRedirect()
            }
          >
            login
          </button>
```

I tried switching to `loginWithRedirect({audience: <client_id>})`. When I use that I get an error response: `Error: “access_denied”, errorDescription: “Service not found: <client_id>`

What do I need to change in order to receive a payload from Auth0?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
        auth0.loginWithRedirect({
            authorizationParams: { audience: `https://${env.PUBLIC_AUTH_DOMAIN}/api/v2/` }
        });
```